# How do immutable ID properties affect .NET equality?

Tags: c#, equality

(*Apologies for the long setup. There is a question in here, I promise.*)

Consider a class `Node` that has an immutable unique ID that is assigned at construction time. This ID is used for serialization when persisting the object graph, among other things. For example, when an object is deserialized, it gets tested against the main object graph by ID to look for a collision and reject it.

Also, a `Node` is only instantiated by a private system, and all public accesses to them are done via the `INode` interface.

So we have something like this common pattern:

```
interface INode
{
    NodeID ID { get; }

    // ... other awesome stuff
}

class Node : INode
{
    readonly NodeID _id = NodeID.CreateNew();

    NodeID INode.ID { get { return _id; } }

    // ... implement other awesome stuff

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var node = obj as INode;
        return ReferenceEquals(node, null) ? false : _id.Equals(node.ID);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

My questions are around these comparison/equality-related features of .NET:

- `IEquatable<T>`
- `IComparable` / `IComparable<T>`
- `operator ==` / `operator !=`

Here are the questions, finally. When implementing a class like `Node`:

- Which of the above interfaces/operators do you implement as well? *Why?*
- Do you extend `IEquatable<T>` from `INode` or `Node`? Given that `IEquatable<T>` only seems to get used (mostly in the BCL) through runtime type checks, is there a point to/not to extend from `INode`?
- For those that you do implement, do you do them just on the class itself, or do you additionally do it on the ID as well?

  - For example, is `IEquatable<NodeID>` also a part of the `Node`?
  - Do you test for `obj as NodeID` in `Equals`?

After working in C# for over a decade, I'm embarrassed not to have a thorough understanding of these interfaces and best practices related to them.

(Note that our .NET systems are built in 95% C#, 5% C++/CLI, 0% VB (if it makes a difference).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable` / `IComparable<T>`, `operator ==` / `operator !=` do you implement as well? Why?

I implement `IEquatable<T>` for circumstances as you are describing. Since dictionaries will make use of this interface, it could be used in a number of hidden places, especially if LInQ is involved. It will be more effecient than the overridden `Equals(object)`, because of type-safety and (for value types) lack of boxing.

Note that `GetHashCode` must also be overridden as well if you are modifying the equality semantics for your class.

I don't normally override operator == unless my type has some kind of numeric interpretation. That is to say, == / != are hardly ever the only operators that I override on a class.

> Do you extend IEquatable from INode or Node? Given that IEquatable only seems to get used (mostly in the BCL) through runtime type checks, is there a point to/not to extend from INode?

I would add it to `INode` if I expected to ever compare nodes for equality. If not, then I wouldn't bother. It may be worthwhile, though, if collections of `INode`s are what you are working with.

> For those that you do implement, do you do them just on the class itself, or do you additionally do it on the ID as well?

If the ID is a simple type, like an integer, then clearly this is unnecessary. If it is a complex type, then separation-of-concerns would require that equality be implemented on the ID's type. This is how I always think about it: what design will allow me to make the biggest changes with the least amount of effort? If you someday decide to change the format of the complex ID object, then do you want to go around the code fixing all the things that this will break? Or do you want to encapsulate all of that logic into the ID class itself. I would certainly choose the latter. (This goes for ToString(), serialization code, and everything else. A Node has no buisness poking around the internals of its complex ID type.)

> For example, is `IEquatable<NodeID>` also a part of the Node?

No, it wouldn't be part of the node. `Node` would implement `IEquatable<Node>` and `NodeId` would implement `IEquatable<NodeId>`.

> Do you test for obj as NodeID in Equals?

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I always implement the `object.Equals(object)` override on `IEquatable<T>` classes like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as Node);
}

public bool Equals(Node node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return false;
    // ... do the type-specific comparison.
}
```

Comment: "It will be more effecient than the overridden Equals(object), because of type-safety and (for value types) lack of boxing." **+1 really good point!** Thanks for the rest as well, that was very helpful guidance. And to clarify what I'm asking in the last two questions: these are about "Node equals NodeID" as an option, to be able to test a `Node` against a `myTestID`, rather than needing to test `Node.ID` against a `myTestID`. In other words - would `IEquatable<NodeID>` on `Node` ever get used? Or adding a `obj as NodeID` test to the `Equals` override? Does that kind of query even make sense?

Comment: @Scott Bilas - I have never before considered implementing IEquatable<T> on a type where T is different from the implementing type itself. Upon first consideration, I do not really feel comfortable with that. I think the equality checks would be confusing for anyone who is maintaining the application. And the NodeID property itself is readily available for comparison, so I am not sure that it would gain you anything. Perhaps there are other scenerios that I am not considering.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node.Equals` method is really just a wrapper for `NodeID.Equals`, so that's where you need to implement the real comparison logic (which I assume would be something like `myIntId == someOtherInt`). Otherwise you will just be using the default `.Equals` behavior that you inherit from `object`.

If I am correct in assuming that your id at the lowest level is just an int, you can implement `IComparable<NodeID>` and `IEquatable<NodeID>` which will simply be wrappers around your int id field as `Int32` already implements `IComparable<int>` and `IEquatable<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of it may also be imperfect, but here goes...

I never do IEquatable, might be a mistake on my part but I figure overriding Equals(obj) is good enough and I can do my type checking in there (or in private helper methods) as needed.  I honestly don't see the point in IEquatable, unless you're just trying to be explicit about be equatable w/ another type.

IComprable is used for sorting/ordering type operations, and is useful if there's some business logic around sorting that can't be captured by overriding GetHashCode.  Again, most of the time I will either do default sorting using GetHashCode or use a linq OrderBy() so there's not much point here.

I always override ==/!= when I override Equals.  It makes the behavior a lot more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed says, if you are comparing equality by NodeID and NodeID is not a value type, then the NodeID class must also implement `IEquatable<NodeID>` (only because of your syntax `_id.Equals(node.ID)`.

That said, if you declare `interface INode : IEquatable<INode>` at the interface level, you still need the actual implementation at the instance level: e.g. for Node:  `public bool Equals(INode other)`

1. This works as long as you are only comparing on a property that was declared in the original interface. If you have a derived class with a new property and you want to also use to compare for equality (say NodeID and NodeDate), then the interface signature will not give your Equals method the access it needs to that property.
2. From a caller's perspective, (a consumer of the API who wants to compare one Node to another) the caller must cast all instances to the interface. This can be what the original intent is, as long as all derived classes don't introduced something the caller needs but not declared in the interface.
3. If you find that you are using additional derived class properties, or that you consumers are not likely to cast to `INode`, then simply extend `IEquatable<Node>` from the derived class (Node).

Joe Albhari has a very understandable and detailed explanation of both interfaces in his [C# in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch06.aspx)

The most important reason for using `IEquatable<T>` is to declare as a contract to consumers of your class that you guarantee a non-default equality implementation. From a framework perspective, you declare `IEquatable<T>` so that framework classes which use a hash algorithm can compare based on your implementation of Equals AND GetHashCode. For example, the HashSet collection, as well as LINQ extensions such as 'Distinct'. That said:

1. Hash algorithms will not work properly if you do not override both `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`;
2. You don't *need* to declare `IEquatable` if your override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`;
3. Or, if you do declare it, than you can omit `Equals(object)` if you implement `Equals(T)`;